# Configure PHP to work with SQL Server along with IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I am trying to configure PHP to work with SQL server along with IIS.

I have successfully connect PHP (version 5.3) to work with IIS. It is working very smooth.

I downloaded PHP from this link (http://php.iis.net/)

But unfortunately , I am not able to use PHP with SQL server. I did check it in ext folder for php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll and php_sqlsrv.dll files and they are present.

They are specified as extension in php.ini file as well.

I am really confused what can be the issue , to make sure that I can use them.

Below PHP code return false

```
<?php
  if (function_exists('mssql_connect')) {
  echo "True.<br />\n";
 } else {
  echo "False.<br />\n";
 }
```

?>

Configure command on phpinfo() shows "without-mssql". I am not sure what is it. ??

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" 
"--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "-
-with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-  
sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11
\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-
dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
```

Any inputs would be helpful. !!!

Thanks !!!

Comment: Does your system meet all the requirements? (http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)

Comment: Yes , it does. I am using Windows 8 64 bit, IIS 8.0 and PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

That may help;

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Did you install this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I also got a problem with the driver for php 5.5 for mssql 2008. I managed to solve it by lowering the version of php with vc9. Now I have PHP Version 5.3.27 and driver for mssql version 2.

Comment: In IIS also set enable for php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about the configuration --without-mssql, there's a comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php that MSSQL has been discontinued since PHP 5.3 and to use the extension SQLSRV, which is available from microsoft at the link given by @Taicho.